# Using LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm trying to use LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression from the Microsoft.Web.Mvc inside an ActionFilter and am wondering if this is the best way to get urls using strongly typed parameters:

```
LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression<HomeController>(
    filterContext.RequestContext,
    RouteTable.Routes,
    x => x.Login()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1263007.aspx) might help.

There is [another](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2009/06/generating-strongly-typed-content-links.html) approach using T4.

And [another](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/02/alternative-to-expressions.aspx), using MVC Futures (might suite best).

I'm looking for the same at the moment, kind a don't want to reference Microsoft.Web.Mvc. :)
There will be this functionality in [Asp.Net Mvc 2](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Road%20Map&referringTitle=Home)