# ASP.NET MVC - Html.ActionLink<T>(expression)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

Is something like `Url.Action<TController>(...)` or `Html.ActionLink<TController>(...)` in MvcContrib?

I see the FluentHtml stuff for forms, but I don't see the same concept applied to urls.

[This post](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=4954) on CodePlex said it was added, but I don't see it in the source anywhere.  Any help would be great.

Edit:

Also, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668319/using-linkbuilder-buildurlfromexpression), but would like to know specifically about MvcContrib.

Comment: That post on codeplex didn't say it's added - there's just a workaround.

Comment: And here is similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668319/using-linkbuilder-buildurlfromexpression

Comment: The CodePlex is a little confusing then since it says, "Added in revision 967". Also, I have that link in my original post, but thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is part of the Futures: "ASP.NET MVC Futures Assembly"

Comment: I can't seem to find this feature in the MVC4Futures nuget package. Was it removed?

Answer (score 0):

jeef3 is correct, it is part of the ASP.NET MVC Futures. Mvccontrib has a dependency on it, so if you are using that library you already have it in your project.